# Swift Changing the Background of SKScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

The Scene Im about to present is linked into an SKScene, how do I change the Background Color of the Scene Programmatically?

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import CoreGraphics
class coolScene: SKScene {


}
```

Comment: Have you even tried to google this before you asked the question?

Comment: yes didnt find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the background via `self.backgroundColor`.